# Proving $\| x + y \| = \| x \| + \| y \|$ implies $\|ax + by\| = \|a x \| + \|by\|$ for any $a,b \geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider $ (R^p, \| \cdot \|)$ a norm space and let $x$ and $y$ be vectors such that $\| x + y \| = \| x \| + \| y \|$. Now show that for any $\alpha$, $\beta$ $\geq 0$, $\|\alpha x + \beta y\| = \|\alpha x \| + \|\beta  y\|$.

This is with regard to general norms, i.e.

$$
||\bar{x}|| \geq 0 
$$
$$
||\alpha\bar{x}|| = |\alpha | ||\bar{x}|| 
$$
$$
||\bar{x} + \bar{y} || \leq ||\bar x|| + ||\bar y|| 
$$
$$
||\bar{x}||= 0 \Leftrightarrow \bar x = 0
$$

With $|| \cdot ||_2$ the proof of this is simple, it implies colinearity of the vectors. For a general norm, I think it implies a somewhat weaker notion of "colinearity", in the hand-wavey sense. This is a homework question and I don't really want the answer---that will not be of much help.

My assessment of the problem is to solve it by making strict use of the four properties of a norm that I've listed above but I am missing some key insight that tells me my maths toolbox is lacking. I would appreciate some problem solving guidance that will eventually lead me to figure this out.

Comment: You may focus on the case for **non**-inner product space.

Comment: In fact is true for all norm associated to a scalar product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you may assume that $a > 0$ and $b > 0$. Then, without loss of generality that $a \geq b$. Set $\lambda := b/a  \in (0,1]$. It suffices to show that $||x+ \lambda y||= ||x|| + ||\lambda y||$. By the triangle inequality, "$\leq$" holds. For the remaining inequality, write
$$
||x|| + ||\lambda y|| = ||x+ y|| - (1-\lambda)||y|| = ||x+y|| - ||(1-\lambda)y|| \leq ||x+ y - (1-\lambda)y||\,,
$$ 
using the assumption in the first equal sign.

Comment: Ha. This I liked. I tried something similar but I had no idea how to write it sensibly or execute it to a successful conclusion. I am glad that I wasn't completely on the wrong track. Thank you so much.

Comment: It was my pleasure.